# MySQL collation for current_time()

Tags: mysql

I am newbie MySQL developer.

I got issue when comparing current_time() with other data

```
select current_time()  > '09:00:00';  --> OK
```

But:

```
select '09:00:00' > current_time();  --> Error
```

Error message: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>'

What's wrong with query 'select '09:00:00' > current_time()'?

Comment: use `cast` because the mysql thinks that you're comparing strings

Comment: You can rewrite the second query as `select current_time() < '09:00:00'` to get the desired result. But interesting observation though.